# Displaying images in webpage from HTML

Tags: php, mysql, ftp

I have a script where by users upload an image on a website and the image gets uploaded to an FTPServer. The name of the file is stored in a database, so when users click on a link, the query string is used as a reference in the Database to get the image name. The only part I'm stuck on right now, is how to display the image on my webpage using php. Is there a specific function to get a copy from the FTP server and display the image? I dont want do download the image to the web server, and then display the image and then delete it, as this could take up a lot of space if the web site has many visitors.

Comment: You either need to transfer the file from the FTP server on-demand and present it to the user, or you need to store the images on the web server.  Pick one.

Comment: What do you mean by 'On-demand'? How to big image hosts do it, they obviously have there web servers and then there storage servers?

Comment: The file doesn't have to be on a hard drive that is physically located in the same case as the web server, but it does need to be in a location that is accessible to the web server, so that the web server can read the file and return its contents to users.  Either that, or the server that hosts the file needs to provide another service (web service, etc.) that the web server would use to request the image file from the host server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "big image hosts" typically have web access to their "storage servers" as well. So when a file is uploaded to their image server it's accessible with a URL. You'd want to determine the url that points to the file you just uploaded and place that in your html (in the `img` tag. Let the user's browser retrieve the image, as opposed to your web server first retrieving it and then displaying the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the image on the web server, once you do that you can display it on your web page however you like, php, ajax, javascript, your choice.